# React - Change child component state value

Tags: reactjs

I have a question about changing child state value from the parent.

I have a design like on the image below. When a datagridrow is selected, row info is sent to datagrid and parent components. Datagrid component keep selectedRowId info in its state, Parent keeps this as well. Parent component has a form and when a row is selected, form elements are filled. When I save the form, I want to clean row selection in the grid. But I cannot find how I can clean datagrid state info(selectedrowId).

I want keep my datagrid component isolated from redux because I want to use datagrid like packaged library. Also I do not want to use ref.

I tried several things but cannot be successful.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

[image]

Comment: A common technique when you need to access state in a child component, is to [lift the state up to the first common ancestor](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). Might be worth looking into.

Comment: As you said I can do this if I send selectedRowId value from Parent to Datagrid but this seems wrong to me. I thought selectedRowId value should not be set outside of Datagrid but this is the most proper way I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I might be misunderstanding the question, but would something like this work?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class A extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: [0, 1, 2],
    selected: 0
  };

  select = val => {
    this.setState({
      selected: val
    });
  };

  reset = () => {
    this.setState({
      selected: 0
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <B {...this.state} select={this.select} />
        <button onClick={this.reset}>reset</button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

class B extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <C
        items={this.props.items}
        select={this.props.select}
        selected={this.props.selected}
      />
    );
  }
}

class C extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { items, selected } = this.props;

    return items.map(i => (
      <div
        onClick={() => this.props.select(i)}
        style={{ color: i === selected ? "red" : "black" }}
      >
        {i}
      </div>
    ));
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<A />, rootElement);
```

Working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/lx4v7njk2z).